# React Native android versions conflict

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, android-studio

I have developed a react native app with SDK android 10 API level 29. The app makes several async calls to fetch data. The app works fine in all android versions till 10. But Android 11 does not make async calls. Is there any kind of compatibility thing that needs to be done to make it work fine?

Comment: What is your `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` in `android/gradle.build`?

Comment: compileSdkVersion is 30 and targetSdkVersion is also 30

Comment: Try upgrading `react-native` to the latest version, if possible. And also post your code here, or maybe try and make a reproducible.